# How to point domain to an web aps inside a Tomcat instance?

Tags: domain, tomcat, port

I have a problem, many days I can't resolve.
**1.** I have 1 VPS CentOS x64, 768 MB RAM, host at `vultr.com`, IP `45.32.45.204`.
**2.** I have 1 website active `codingvn.com` (I use script to point domain to web app, really, I don't know how to do this manually by myself).
**3.** I have 1 web app at `http://45.32.45.204:81/` (or `codingvn.com:81` is the same).
**4.** I want point domain `muabannhadatpro.com` to `http://45.32.45.204:81/`. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A domain (or more accurately an A record on your domain) is just a pointer to an IP address. The port number is a completely different deal.

http://domain.com works because browsers and other UAs "know" that the default port for http is 80. If you wanted to run an http server on port 81 in domain.com you'd have to access it through http://domain.com:81 to override the default port.

Must you really have the app on a different port? Have you tried using virtual hosts instead? Seems more in line with what you want to accomplish.